# Find the extrema of $f(x,y) = e^{1/x^2y}$ (defined as $f(x,y)=0$ when $xy=0$)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm mostly concerned with how to properly justify my answer.

We know that $f$ is not differentiable along the axes; the simplest way to prove this is by showing that $f$ is not continuous at $(a,b)$ when either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

For the rest of the domain, $\nabla f(x,y)=(e^{1/x^2y}(-2x^{-2}y^{-1}),e^{1/x^2y}(-x^{-2}y^{-2}))$, which is never zero. Hence, the only critical points are the axes.

Since $f$ is always nonnegative, we know that these points are definitely minima. This is pretty much obvious, given that $e^{1/x^2y} > 0$.

C'est fini? I mean, is this answer what's expected of the exercise?

Comment: Looks fine to me.